# ¿Como hacer un condicional en una funcion?

Tags: sql

[image: Como colocar un condicional que si no existe la factura me mande un mensaje de error]
Eh intentado hacer un if y else pero me sale error , una ayuda porfavor , la funcion cumple su proposito pero me piden ese condicional eh intentado pero no me sale , una guia porfavor

En la segunda imagen hay una prueba pero me sale error no se que estoy haciendo mal , porfavor , guienme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El codigo debe ir como texto

Comment: Intenta no poner imagenes donde debería ir código, consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

En la definición de la función se indica que debe de retornar un dato tipo money, pero no se retorna.

```
Create function dbo.miFuncion (
@numero int)
returns money
begin
    Declare @retorno money;
    if (5<@numero)
    begin
        -- To Do
        set @retorno = 1;
    end
    else
    begin
        -- To Do
        set @retorno = 2;
    end
    return @retorno;
end;
```

Así de simple puede ser.

[image: Resultado]

En el enlace, tienes ejemplos de funciones con varias instrucciones.

[UDF escalares](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Independientemente de que te haya intentado prestar una pequeña ayuda sin utilizar tú código, mira con atención estos enlaces. Puedes darle a [edit](/edit) para modificar la pregunta siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Y como ya te han indicado, cuando solicites ayuda, el código siempre como texto, y no como imagen.

Comment: Y si quiero colocar un mensaje de que ha sido registrada  como hago , ya que uso raiserror('Se ha registrado . 17 ,1') , pero me dice que su uso es no valido

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485034/how-to-report-an-error-from-a-sql-server-user-defined-function